# Calulated Column with Multiple IF Statement

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Ok, I know I am missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Trying to write a calculated column with multiple IF statements.  Here is what I have.

```
=IF([Status]="OPEN",[Date Opened]+3,"")IF([Status]="REFERRAL",[Date Opened]+5,"")IF([Status]="ONLY",[Date Opened]+10,"")IF([Status]="PENDING",[Date Opened]+30,"")IF([Status]="REOPEN",[Date Opened]+30,"")
```

As always any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula syntax for **Nestd IF** is not correct, you need to add the new **IF** at the previous **IF-ELSE** as the following:

```
=IF([Status]="OPEN",[Date Opened]+3,IF([Status]="REFERRAL",[Date Opened]+5,IF([Status]="ONLY",[Date Opened]+10,IF([Status]="PENDING",[Date Opened]+30,IF([Status]="REOPEN",[Date Opened]+30,"")))))
```

Comment: you are welcome,